# No vaild message received from loaded iframe for iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, fine-uploader

Some help with the following please.

Hi Ray, I am now getting response correctly back for IE7/8. However it comes back immediately, where firefox is taking its time to upload with a percentage bar to indicate this. I am worried cause someone may upload and then see it is done then save and the video won't be there. Any suggestions as to why IE7/8 would show response immediately. Hope that makes sense

Thank you for response, however still did not work.  Get upload fail.  Do I pass the response back as text/html or text/plain

also on the oncomplete function is that the correct response log?

```
uploader = $jq('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            //endpoint: 'http://video-api.shannons.com.au/api/upload/upload.php',
            endpoint: 'http://crowleyroofing.radiusmedia.com.au/uploader-test.php',
            params: {
                ClientToken: token,
                ApplicationResponse: 'FineUploader'
            },
            inputName: 'FileUpload'
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true
        },
        multiple: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions : ['mp4','mov','ogm','ogv','ogx','webm','flv','avi','m4v','mkv','wmv'],
            sizeLimit : 52428800
        },
        showMessage: function(message) {
            $('.video-error').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
        }
    })
    .on('submit', function(event, id) {
        $('.qq-upload-button').hide();
        $('.qq-upload-list').show();
    })
    .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
        console.log(response);
        //$jq('.qq-upload-status-text').html(response);

        /*$jq('#event-post-form').prepend('<input id="mediatoken" type="hidden" name="mediatoken" value="' + response.Data.MediaId + '">');
        var size = $('.qq-upload-size').text();
        var html = '' + name + ' ' + size + ' <span class="icon"><em class="club-tick"></em></span>';
        $jq('.qq-upload-status-text').html(html);*/
    });
```

PHP here

```
 <?php

function gen_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,

        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,

        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
}

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']!="XMLHttpRequest")) {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type, cache-control');
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $data = array("success" => true, "uuid" => gen_uuid());
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo "$json <script src=\"http://crowleyroofing.radiusmedia.com.au/iframe.xss.response-3.9.0-3.js\"></script>";
}
```

?>

This is the response i get back from ie9/8

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received 1 files or inputs.

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Sending upload request for 0

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received iframe load event for CORS upload request (iframe name 0_89b9b578-b08e-4221-be2b-a1bac04792c8)

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] Received the following window message: '{"success":true,"uuid":"9da17ad5-ad6a-40cd-81b5-226e837db45b"}'

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] No valid message received from loaded iframe for iframe name 0_89b9b578-b08e-4221-be2b-a1bac04792c8

[FineUploader 3.9.0-3] iframe loaded

Answer (score 0):

Your aren't returning a proper response for cross-origin uploads initiated by IE9 or older.  [As the documentation states](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/), you must return a text/html response that contains a script tag pointing to the `iframe.xss.response.js` file, and a valid JSON string that contains a `success` property with a value of `true` AND a `uuid` property with the value equal to the UUID of the associated file.

Your response code should look something like this:

```
$data = array("success" => true, "uuid" => "9da17ad5-ad6a-40cd-81b5-226e837db45b");
$json = json_encode($data);
echo "$json <script src=\"http://crowleyroofing.radiusmedia.com.au/iframe.xss.response-3.9.0-3.js\"></script>";
```

Your will need to replace the value of the `uuid` property with the value of the `qquuid` parameter Fine Uploader sends with the upload request.

Also, note the following, unrelated issues with your code:

- There is no need to enable the `cors.allowXdr` option.  This is only used if you have the delete file feature enabled in cross origin environments.
- The `debug` option defaults to `false`, so you don't need to explicitly set this.
- The `cors.sendCredentials` option defaults to `false`, so you don't need to explicitly set this.

Comment: Hi Ray,  I updated my question at the top, still not working for me.

Comment: Your code still does not look correct.  If you are using that exact code, then it will not work.  As I mentioned, you must include the UUID of the associated file with the response.  You have hard-coded a UUID in your response above.  After you fix that, if it is still not working, you will need to include all console log messages (with `debug` set to `true`) and the request/response data per IE9's network tab.

Comment: Hi Ray,  How do I set a UUID in php?

Comment: Hi Ray please above I have updated my code and php uploader code as well.  You will also see the response back from ie8/9 as well.  Still having an issue.

Comment: It's a bit late over here.  I'll get back to your question in the morning (about 9 hours from now).

Comment: @user1015671 You must extract the UUID from the request, then set that value in your response.  Do not generate a new UUID.  You must extract the value of the `qquuid` parameter in the request and set that to the value of the `uuid` property of your response.

Comment: Hi Ray, how do i get the UUID within PHP.  Is it extracted from $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got IE8/9 to work now.  However when I upload a 16mb file the response back is immediate.  It's not loading or sending the file to the server for a larger file.  Is there another setting for large files.  It did work for a 1.7 mb file.  I configured fineuploader to allow 50mb files.  Any ideas??

Comment: Hi Ray,  I am now getting response correctly back for IE7/8.  However it comes back immediately, where firefox is taking its time to upload with a percentage bar to indicate this.  I am worried cause someone may upload and then see it is done then save and the video won't be there.  Any suggestions as to why IE7/8 would show response immediately.  Hope that makes sense